# meteor-add consistently fails on large packages

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

Working on a meteor project for the first time and attempting to install the `arillio:flow-router-helpers` package always fails.

I've installed smaller package previously without issue - my assumption is that due to the dependency on the larger `coffeescript` package, some sort of network timeout is occurring in the download phase, but the extraction phase is continuing regardless and failing.

Here's what happens. Install package:

```
meteor add arillo:flow-router-helpers
```

`coffeescript` package starts to download:

```
Downloading coffeescript@1.0.17...        [=                         ] 2% 381.3s
```

This will continue for about a minute or so, but before reaching 100%, will stop and start the extraction phase:

```
 Extracting coffeescript@1.0.17...         \
```

Which then immediately fails with:

```
/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.354htk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
  throw error;
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/mt-spnavf/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/program.json'
at Error (native)
```

Are there any known workarounds or solutions to this problem? I've attempted the download about 15 times now with no success.

EDIT: Should have made clear that I have really a slow internet connection (.3 Mbps, at best), hence my assumption that the problem might be related to download time of the package.

Comment: It may well be timing out - some package loads take time even on a good link

Comment: I just tried adding the package. It installed both ```zimmie:active-route``` and ```flow-router-helper``` just fine. Took some time though, but works well

Answer (score 0):

`export METEOR_WAREHOUSE_URLBASE=https://d3fm2vapipm3k9.cloudfront.net`

fixed the issue for me.